# No Wi-Fi adapter found

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

“No Wi-Fi adapter found” is the message I got after installing `Ubuntu 17.10`.

With the following command line `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`, I got the following message. How could I fix that issue?

[image: output]

Here is the error shown in the settings:

[image: error]

Comment: If it is a pci[e] adapter, it should show in lspci, even if it is not supported. Can you provide raw lspci output without grepping?

Answer (score 0):

The wifi hardware adapter is not shown in your output. I only see LAN adapters.

It is difficult to provide a solution with this information.

1. Open the network connection manager and ensure "Enable Wi-fi" is ticked"
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v7Am.jpg
2. Open a Terminal Window and run this command to see if it is recognized by NetworkManager. You should see, amongst others, a device of type "wifi" in that list, if not then your wifi-card/device is not enabled on your computer.

> $ nmcli device status

```
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION
...
wlp2s0      wifi
...
```

What is the output on your computer?

2. Are you also connected to the Internet via the LAN? Try `ping -c3 www.google.com`
3. Is it in this list?

> $ ip address show

4. Perhaps it is disabled in the BIOS UEFI?

Comment: so I am already stopped at the second step. So what should I do if my wifi card is not enables on my cmoputer (lenovo-ideapad)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Then, looking for several places I solved following the below steps.

First of all, I tried to download the network kernel from site --> https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/17.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb.html

If your architecture is x64,

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Then, I saw the configuration of network service

```
 cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

By default, there are

```
 [main]`
 plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

 [ifupdown]
 managed=false

 [device]
 wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

if it is different of yours, change it.

Then, you need to restart the kernel configuration.

```
  sudo service network-manager restart
```

Reboot the computer.

On bios, change the boot secure:

```
boot secure: disabled   ->    boot secure: enabled
```

And ok.

Works in ubuntu 17, Positivo Stilo XCi7660.

bye