# Ubuntu 18.04: No WiFi adapter found - secure boot disabled

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

I am using Lenovo T460 running 18.04.2 and kernel ***Linux 4.15.0-46-generic***. The wireless settings shows ***"No Wi-Fi adapter found"***. I've disabled secure boot from start. I've tried to enable Wi-Fi again like in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075009/259316) with no result.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I've done another apt update and a firmware update.

```
$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

```
$ sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reference: [Can't view Wifi networks after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760075/cant-view-wifi-networks-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04)

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl

[    3.369900] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.379631] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.488969] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x204
[    8.672033] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    8.672038] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    8.672039] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    8.672090] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 24f38086 00100406 0280003a 00000000 e1000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672094] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    8.672096] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    8.672136] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 18489004 00000040 20000000 08000000 00000000 00000000 00000019 00000000
[    8.672139] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000014 08040005 00000201 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
[    8.672143] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[    8.672167] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672168] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672170] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[    8.672183] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 9d128086 00100007 060400f1 00810000 00000000 00000000 00040400 200000f0
[    8.672185] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: e100e100 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 000003ff
[    8.672187] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.2) AER cap structure:
[    8.672196] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672198] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [2] uCode section
[    8.672351] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.695742] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[    8.708278] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

```
$ iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.
virbr1    no wireless extensions.
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
vmnet1    no wireless extensions.
vmnet8    no wireless extensions.
virbr1-nic  no wireless extensions.
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

In the end the solution I think should be in some BIOS setting or reinstalling the driver (maybe from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)?)

If I restart with the previous kernel, 4.15.0-45, the problem remains, with a different version of the module and a shorter error log.

```
alex@alex-T460:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.501905] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.561037] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: uCode file size 16304073 does not match expected size
[    3.561439] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.563587] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.576571] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.611226] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x204
[    4.702726] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    4.702731] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    4.726591] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[    4.772710] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110



$ ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1745176 mar 30  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2351636 mar 30  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2394060 nov 17  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2120860 dic 14 14:09 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2227284 dic  5  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2310116 dic  6  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16304073 mar 20 16:07 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 16555134 mar 20 15:18 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
```

```
alex@alex-T460:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-45-generic root=UUID=1619cba6-c8ee-44db-be4f-c338533a2e65 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
```

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

---

After renaming last two modules downloaded from Intel site, the kernel loads the previous one, but it fails too:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.391361] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.402953] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.402972] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.404560] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.413676] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.560484.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.451641] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x204
[    8.672055] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[    8.672060] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[    8.672062] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[    8.672102] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 24f38086 00100406 0280003a 00000000 e1000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672105] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[    8.672107] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[    8.672147] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 18489004 00000040 20000000 08000000 00000000 00000000 00000019 00000000
[    8.672150] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000014 08040005 00000201 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
[    8.672154] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[    8.672179] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672180] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672182] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[    8.672195] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 9d128086 00100007 060400f1 00810000 00000000 00000000 00040400 200000f0
[    8.672197] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: e100e100 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 000003ff
[    8.672199] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.2) AER cap structure:
[    8.672208] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672210] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    8.672357] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [2] uCode section
[    8.672364] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.695695] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[    8.708417] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

---

After removing the downloaded modules and reinstalled the firmware:

```
$ ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1745176 mar 30  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2351636 mar 30  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2394060 nov 17  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2120860 dic 14 14:09 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2227284 dic  5  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2310116 dic  6  2017 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2448976 apr 25  2018 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2486572 dic 14 13:54 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Even from another distro, Fedora live, I have the same error. So I think or is something about the BIOS or the wifi card was damaged in some way..

```
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   11.920684] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.103981] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.e91976c0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.320908] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x204
[   17.376022] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   17.376024] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   17.376025] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   17.376064] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 24f38086 00100406 0280003a 00000000 f1000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   17.376065] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01308086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 000001ff
[   17.376066] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   17.376104] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 00489004 00000040 20000000 08000000 00000000 00000000 00000019 00000000
[   17.376105] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000014 08040005 00000201 d55555d5 d55555d5 d55555d5 80008040 001f0042
[   17.376109] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   17.376132] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   17.376133] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   17.376134] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[   17.376146] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 9d128086 00100007 060400f1 00810000 00000000 00000000 00040400 200000f0
[   17.376148] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: f100f100 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 000003ff
[   17.376149] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi root port (0000:00:1c.2) AER cap structure:
[   17.376157] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00010000 00060011 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   17.376159] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   17.376305] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [2] uCode section
[   17.376311] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   17.399460] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failing on timeout while stopping DMA channel 8 [0xa5a5a5a2]
[   17.411055] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ uname -a
Linux localhost-live 4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Oct 20 23:24:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.32.1
e2fsck 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 3802607 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 582619/9166848 files (1.3% non-contiguous), 16861084/36647680 blocks
[liveuser@localhost-live ~]$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.32.1
e2fsck 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 376/12214272 files (1.1% non-contiguous), 22723088/48828160 blocks
```

---

**Update:**
Tried also disabling power management as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/85223/259316) but it didn't work

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/blacklist
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless
```

---

**SOLVED:**
I changed the wireless card (with AC 8265)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91378/discussion-on-question-by-bastapasta-ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-secur).

Answer (score 3):

**Lets first check the file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Lets remove the incorrect drivers, and try and reinstall the firmware files...**

`sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all` # remove incorrect dkms driver

`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` # remove incorrect broadcom driver

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software database

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware` # reinstall firmware

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Recheck wireless operation.

**Update #1:**

Found hugely bloated Intel firmware at `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode` and `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode`. Removed them and reinstalled `linux-firmware`, and the code sizes look good now, but it still doesn't work.

**Update #2:**

Booting Fedora Live results in the same wireless errors that we see with Ubuntu. Suspect a problem with the wi-fi card. It may need re-seating or replacement.

Comment: Hi, I'm in office now and I can't use a live Ubuntu, why is a fsck necessary? 
Anyway I followed the other steps to remove wrong drivers and reinstall firmware, but nothing changed. Which is strange because at least dmesg should have shown less errors

Comment: @bastaPasta you `fsck` to make sure there's no file system corruption.

Comment: Do you know how to replace it with [Intel drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) (iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode) or with a [backport](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/)? (https://askubuntu.com/a/706030/259316). After I copied the Intel 36.ucode in /lib/firmware it has failed loading 34.0.1 again looking at dmsg

Comment: Try booting to the prior kernel and see if you still have the same problem. Report back.

Comment: Tried unsuccessfully. Details in the post

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works. Report back.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @bastaPasta Oh, I think I found the problem. Go to `/lib/firmware/` and rename `iwlwifi-8000C-34` and `-36` to `iwlwifi-8000C-34.HOLD` and `-36.HOLD` and reboot. Recheck wireless. If that doesn't work then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware` again, reboot and retest. Let me know if I need to update my answer.

Comment: The renaming didn't work, see original post. I even tried woth a usb Ubuntu 18.10 and there were the same problem. I'm going to try the reinstall

Comment: @bastaPasta delete the two .HOLD files and reinstall `linux-firmware`. Then `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-*`.

Comment: Updated with some BIOS photo, since I couldn't find that "Intel Platform Trust"

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me one time. It turns out I disabled Intel Platform Trust Technology in BIOS. Making sure that was enabled fixed my issue.

Comment: I've immediately searched it full of hope, but there is nothing with a similar name. I'm going to search if on my Lenovo there is something equivalent

Comment: @bastaPasta see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000007452/mini-pcs.html

Comment: How much is dangerous to [restore factory keys](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/PROBLEM-BIOS-UPDATE-FOR-LENOVO-Y700-17ISK-Laptop/m-p/3385593/highlight/true#M3231)?

Comment: @bastaPasta It might break stuff... like Windows?

Comment: I have only Ubuntu on this laptop

Comment: @bastaPasta I'd wait to see chili555's answer to my last comments. Is your TPM enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: Updated with some BIOS photo, since I couldn't find that "Intel Platform Trust"

Comment: I found that option under Security chip selection and it is already on PTT which use Intel platform trusted technology

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the other solutions above and they didn't work, try clearing CMOS on the motherboard. Doing this finally solved my problem.